# Traveling from UK to Spain with prescription painkillers

Tags: uk, spain, prescription

I will soon be flying from UK to Spain (direct flight with Jet2). I am currently recovering after a surgery and use opioid-based prescription painkillers for pain management (codeine).

I have a hospital discharge letter listing this medication and the box with the medication has this same hospital label and my name on it. I am not planning to take everything with me, only enough for the duration of the trip plus a bit extra just in case.

From what I have seen and read, I shouldn't have any issues taking it with me to Spain (and back), but can anyone confirm please?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have everything in order. As long as it is for a short term and every medecine is accounted for, you should be fine.

I let you this information from the Spanish consulate :

> You can travel with medicines that have been prescribed by your general practitioner (GP) or specialist, provided they have been
> legally acquired in the United Kingdom and you carry the amount
> necessary for your trip (usually considered in this case the
> equivalent of less than three (3) months of treatment). It is
> advisable to travel with a letter from your doctor, a copy of the
> prescription and bring the medication in its original packaging.
> Please note that certain medications may be subject to specific
> authorization. For more information, review the Home Office-Drugs
> Licensing and Compliance Unit (DLCU) page.
>
> In any case, review and verify the information provided by your
> airline.
> Finally, you can also consult the information provided by the Spanish
> Medicines Agency at the following link https://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/londres/es/Informacion-servicios-consulares/Paginas/Preguntas%20frecuentes/AsistenciaSocial.aspx
> .

Comment: Hey ESACom and welcome to travelstackexchange!
Could you provide the urls that are shown in your text by "linkIt opens in new window"?

Comment: Find attached, its in spanish : 

https://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/londres/es/Informacion-servicios-consulares/Paginas/Preguntas%20frecuentes/AsistenciaSocial.aspx#:~:text=Qu%C3%A9%20debo%20hacer%3F-,%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B,3)%20meses%20de%20tratamiento).